# Sencha ext js changing column text

Tags: extjs, grid

I want to call reconfigure on a grid to change the column text like this example

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#reconfigure-grid

However I want to do it from an external control that has nothing to do with the grid.

Need to find the reference to the grid because when I pass it into a variable, I get a no method error when calling reconfigure

Any help appreciate thanks

***EDIT***

If you have a look at the link in the post, then this function:

```
onShowOfficesClick: function(){ 
var grid = this.down('grid'); 
Ext.suspendLayouts();
grid.setTitle('Employees');
grid.reconfigure(this.createOfficeStore()
```

Shows how to reconfigure a grid.

What I'm trying to do is get the grid reference from an external function, not sure if its possible

Here's some of my code

```
var Social_Environment_Grid = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
```

Goes to to create a store, not so relevant

Then is a seperate Jquery function I want to call

```
Social_Environment_Grid.reconfigure(false, newColumArray)
```

But I get an error Social_Environment_Grid has no method reconfigure, so I guess this is not the correct object reference

Hope this makes sense

***Edit Fixed***

Fixed it thanks to everyones comments and answers here was my problem

```
 var Panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'fit',
    height: 400,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox', // Arrange child items vertically
        align: 'stretch', // Each takes up full width
        padding: 5
    },
    items: [{ // Results grid specified as a config object with an xtype of 'grid'
        xtype: 'grid',
        id: 'Panelxx1',
        columns: [
```

Then call

```
Ext.getCmp('Panelxx1').reconfigure(false,alternativeIndex);
```

I was not referencing the grid, and also not calling the object reference correctly, thanks for everyone's help

Comment: There is a `reconfigure` method in `Ext.grid.Panel.prototype` so, except if you'd explicitly deleted it (from the prototype!), the variable you end up with is not a reference to a grid panel... Could you show us your code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your response rixo , I've added some more code to the question

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. The variable you declared refers to a store, not a grid.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I will check this also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you must do in order to update your grid's view is calling the `reconfigure` method on the grid object. That is, the `grid` variable in your code example.

As stated in the [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure), this method accepts a new store as its first argument, and a new columns array as its second, both optional.

So, if the fields of your data model change, you must create a new store with the updated fields. If your store is based on a Model, you can first update it using the static [`setField`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-setFields) method (e.g. `My.Model.setFields(...)`), and then, your create a new store using this model, and you pass it to the grid's `reconfigure` method.

If your data fields do not change, you can skip the first argument like you do in your example, and use only an array for the new columns.

Now, your problem seems to be to get a reference to your grid object in the place you want to call `reconfigure`. There are many ways to achieve this. The simplest one (except using a global variable, which you should really never do), would be to give your grid an id with the `id` config option, and when you need your grid, you can get a reference with `Ext.getCmp(myGridId)`. This is probably not the cleanest in your situation, but we would need to know the context in which you want to call `reconfigure` in order to give more appropriated suggestions.